# pyramid numbers in alternative reverse order

Tags: java

I was asked to write code for the below structure:

> ```
>      1
>     3 2
>    4 5 6
>   10 9 8 7
> 11 12 13 14 15
> ```

And I tried the below code, which works, yet I'm wondering if there is any better approach than this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int no_of_rows=5;
    int c=0;

    for(int i=1;i<=no_of_rows;i++){

        for(int k=i;k<no_of_rows;k++){

            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        if(i%2!=0){
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            c++;
            System.out.print(c +" ");
        }
        }
        else{
            int a[] = new int [i+1];
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
                c++;
                a[j]=c;                 
            }
            for(int j=i-1;j>=0;j--){
               System.out.print(a[j]+" ");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Is there any better implementation or am I doing it right?

Comment: This sort of question is better suited to [code-review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only improvement is to remove the array in this block:

```
    else{
        int a[] = new int [i+1];
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            c++;
            a[j]=c;                 
        }
        for(int j=i-1;j>=0;j--){
           System.out.print(a[j]+" ");
        }

    }
```

We can easily calculate those values used in reverse order without the need of an additional array:

```
  c += i;//Update c
  for(int j = 0; j < i ; j++){
      System.out.print((c - j) + " " );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

While your solution does work it is not clear what it is doing without careful study.

I would use something more sophisticated like an `Iterable` for extra clarity:

```
/**
 * Generates a range of numbers from start to end.
 *
 * Automatically reverses the sequence if end < start.
 */
public static class Range implements Iterable<Integer> {

    private final int start;
    private final int end;
    private final int step;

    public Range(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        // Automagically pick the direction.
        this.step = start > end ? -1 : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Integer>() {
            // Start there.
            private int n = start;
            // Have we finished yet?
            private boolean finished = false;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return !finished;
            }

            @Override
            public Integer next() {
                int next = n;
                if (n != end) {
                    // Step one more.
                    n = n + step;
                } else {
                    // We're emitting the `end` value - time to stop.
                    finished = true;
                }
                return next;
            }

        };
    }

}

public void test() {
    int rows = 5;
    int start = 1;
    int count = 1;

    for (int row = 1; row <= rows; row++) {
        // Gap at the start.
        for (int k = row; k < rows; k++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        // Odd rows go forward.
        Range r = (row & 1) == 0 ? new Range(start + count - 1, start) : new Range(start, start + count - 1);
        // Print a row.
        for (int i : r) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        // Start after last row finished.
        start += count;
        // One more number.
        count += 1;
        System.out.println("");
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        new Test().test();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

This solution also takes no extra memory as n increases.

Comment: @VigneshParamasivam - What errors? You can create an empty class called `Test` and paste this in - it should work untouched.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, first of all, you should calculate the `rows` instead of hard-coding it as `5`

I wrote this snippet, to print the output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    int x = 105;
    int rows = Double.valueOf(Math.sqrt(2 * x)).intValue();
    int n = 1;
    for (int r = 1; r <= rows; r++) {
        System.out.print(new String(new char[rows - r]).replace("\0", " "));
        if ((r & 1) != 0)
            for (int i = n; i < n + r && n + r <= x; i++)
                System.out.printf("%s%s", i, i == n + r - 1 || i == x ? "\n" : " ");
        else
            for (int i = n + r - 1 > x ? x : n + r-1; i >= n; i--)
                System.out.printf("%s%s", i, i == n  ? "\n" : " ");
        n = n + r;
    }
}
```

- I used the `x` to indicate the number, it could be changed into a method with argument easily.
- for bigger `x`, the output may look not so nice, since I set single space the separator between numbers, but big number could be much longer. But the layout is anyway kept.

output for `x=105`:

```
             1
            3 2
           4 5 6
          10 9 8 7
         11 12 13 14 15
        21 20 19 18 17 16
       22 23 24 25 26 27 28
      36 35 34 33 32 31 30 29
     37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
    55 54 53 52 51 50 49 48 47 46
   56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66
  78 77 76 75 74 73 72 71 70 69 68 67
 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91
105 104 103 102 101 100 99 98 97 96 95 94 93 92
```

Comment: what if `x=50`(for ex), then id does not form a pyramid structure right? that is why i specified the rows instead of last digit.

Comment: @VigneshParamasivam it is not handled, is it required? if yes, we have to fill the placeholder for reverse case. and it is also easy,  in the `else` block, check the diff between `x` and `n+r-1`